# vue - Pass index to method onLoad

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to pass a `v-for` `index` to a `method` on page load? The common way I pass `index` is using `@change` event with a select drop down, but this time I'm creating a report without a select drop down.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <span>{{item.name}}</item>
    @onLoad='getData(index)'
</div>

methods: {
    getData(index) {
      axios.get('api', {
        params: { id: this.items[index].item_id}
      })
      .then({response=>})
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mounted()` component's function to populate items on the component load.

```
mounted()
{

    this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
        axios.get('api', {
            params: {id: this.items[index].item_id}
        })
            .then(response => {

                item.updated_property = response.data;
                Vue.set(this.items, index, item);
     });

    });
}
```

Comment: Weird that I'm having this error `Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: item is not defined"`

Comment: @JimERussel, I have corrected the typos, can you check now?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I tried your code with `mounted()` but I'm having trouble since I'm also getting the data from `created()`. What I did was call the function inside a function and pasted your code above, it now works wonders. Thank you so much!